# IntelliJ, Powershell and Git

Tags: git, powershell, intellij-idea

Hey I am having some trouble getting git to be recognised in a powershell terminal inside IntelliJ. The powershell terminal loads fine within IntelliJ and I have added git to the Path. Which allows any stand-alone powershell instances the ability to recognise git commands, but no matter what I try the powershell instance in IntelliJ just isn't picking it up. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'Shell Path' in IntelliJ ('Preferences-->Tools-->Terminal-->Shell Path').